# Google Sheets Script Copy Values from Array to Column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm have an issue where I'm trying to copy values from an array to another column within my active sheet. While I have been following code samples and tutorials on copying values, I get an error with my current setup saying that my `Range is not found` for 
`sheet.getRange(resultsArray.length).copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1:F24")).setValues(resultsArray);`

I'm not too sure which range it is coming from, but my assumption is the range within the `.copyTo` method

Here is my full function:

```
function extractBranded() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var keywords = /ipad game|game system/;

    if (data[i][0].match(keywords)) {

      var resultsArray = [];
      var brandedKeywords = data[i][0];


      resultsArray = brandedKeywords;

      Logger.log(resultsArray.length);

      Logger.log(shopkeepKeywords);

      sheet.getRange(resultsArray.length).copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1:F24")).setValues(resultsArray);


    } else {

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

sheet.getRange wants at least 2 arguments: 
(row, col)
 or 
(row, col, number or rows, number of cols)

sheet.getRange(resultsArray.length) is not a valid range, so you probably need:

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,resultsArray.length,1)
```

Comment: Hey @Riel, that fixed my first issue, but now I run into the following issue. `TypeError: Cannot call method "setValues" of undefined. ` Any thoughts on why the setValue is coming up as this problem? When I log my variable, I see that values exist so I'm not sure why it is saying that it is undefined

Comment: Not setValues in undefined but the object you want to setValues to. CopyTo already copies te values and format and does not return anything. I would use copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 6)); instead of F1:F6